# Play sounds and programmatically decide audio output

Tags: windows-phone-8

i want to play a sound on a windows phone 8.0 application and decide myself, whether the output is speakerphone, earpiece or bluetooth (if available).

```
    public void playSound()
    {
        var streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(_soundName, UriKind.Relative));
        SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(streamResourceInfo.Stream);

        // throws exception (access denied). IP_CAP_VOIP Capability is set! 
        //AudioRoutingManager.GetDefault().SetAudioEndpoint(_audioRoutingEndpoint);

        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        effect.Play();
    }
```

As i've read, the SetAudioEndpoint is for routing audio from VoIP applications, so it may not work together with the XNA SoundEffect class.

long story short: is it possible to programmatically decide where the audio output should be? without c++ chatterbox voip overhead?